# Symfony2 - Embedded Form is not saving parent ID

Tags: forms, symfony, collections, doctrine, embed

I have this proble when I embed form into another, they have many to one relationship, but when saving the data children does not save the id into database.

Let's say my parent Entity is University and child is Faculty. One University can have many Faculties.

Parent.

```
class University
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="UniversityFaculty", mappedBy="university", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $faculties;

    public function __construct()
{
    $this->faculties = new ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * Add faculty
 *
 * @param UniversityFaculty $faculty
 *
 * @return University
 */
public function addFaculty(UniversityFaculty $faculty)
{
    $this->faculties[] = $faculty;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove faculty
 *
 * @param UniversityFaculty $faculty
 */
public function removeFaculty(UniversityFaculty $faculty)
{
    $this->faculties->removeElement($faculty);
}
```

Child.

```
class Faculty
{
    /**
     * @var University
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="University", inversedBy="faculties", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="university_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $university;

    // ...
```

I built a form:

```
->add('faculties', BootstrapCollectionType::class, array(
            'type'                  => UniversityFacultyType::class,
            'allow_add'             => true,
            'allow_delete'          => true,
            'add_button_text'       => 'Add Faculty',
            'delete_button_text'    => 'Delete Faculty',
            'sub_widget_col'        => 9,
            'button_col'            => 3,
            'required'              => false,
            'by_reference'          => false
        ))
```

`BootstrapCollectionType` is simply `CollectionType` customized by BraincraftBootstrapBundle so I don't need to creat JS and CSS for ADD or REMOVE buttons.

I read documentation and already added add and remove methods inside University entity, also `cascade={"persist"}` and `by_reference => false`, and everything works fine except that it still is not saving University ID inside Faculty table in DB (other columns are saved).

Any ideas what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing assigning an University to a new Faculty.

There are many ways to do it.

For example:

```
public function addFaculty(UniversityFaculty $faculty)
{
    $faculty->setUniversity($this);
    $this->faculties[] = $faculty;

    return $this;
}
```

Or:

```
->add('faculties', BootstrapCollectionType::class, array(
            'type'                  => UniversityFacultyType::class,
            'allow_add'             => true,
            'allow_delete'          => true,
            'add_button_text'       => 'Add Faculty',
            'delete_button_text'    => 'Delete Faculty',
            'sub_widget_col'        => 9,
            'button_col'            => 3,
            'required'              => false,
            'by_reference'          => false,
            'empty_data' => function (FormInterface $form) {
               $faculty = UniversityFaculty();
               $faculty->setUniversity($form->getParent()->getData());
               return $price; 
            },
        ))
```

Maybe, University is in `$form->getData()`, not it `$form->getParent()->getData()`. But somewhere in the form

Comment: I thought of the first option before, but it seemed incorrect way to do since doctrine:generate:entities does not generate properly add methods and you have to modify it yourself. Anyway first option seems much better than second one. Thank you for the answer!